# VB.Net Dropdownlist has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I keep getting the above error, i have tried setting the dropdownlist to new dropdownlist and then binding after but that then prevents any binding at all. my code:

```
Private Sub putStudentInstitutionList()
        Dim strSql As String
        Dim rtnSchoolData As DataSet
        strSql = "SELECT schoolID, name FROM tSchool WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY name"
        rtnSchoolData = cDB.executeReturn(strSql)

        ddlInstitution.Items.Clear()
        If rtnSchoolData.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ddlInstitution.AppendDataBoundItems = True
        ddlInstitution.DataSource = rtnSchoolData.Tables(0)
        ddlInstitution.DataTextField = "name"
        ddlInstitution.DataValueField = "schoolID"
        ddlInstitution.DataBind()
        ddlInstitution.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("", ""))
        ddlInstitution.SelectedIndex = 0
        ddlInstitution.Items.Insert(1, New ListItem("All Schools", "ALL"))
    End If
End Sub
```

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated, the issue occurs on postback as it is attempting to re-bind the dropdownlist.
Wrapping it in a condition based on page.postback doesn't work as the dropdownlist is populated on the bases of another dropdownlist so is (in essence) bound on postback

Comment: You could add these items declaratively on the aspx and set the `DopDownList`'s `AppendDataBoundItems` to `true`. Apart from that i assume that you have missed to call this method only `if(!IsPostBack)` .

Comment: Hi Tim, would setting that in html rather than vb make any odds? It isn't possible to use `if(!IsPostBack)` as the original creators of the app have developed it in such a way that if `if(!IsPostBack)` is used the `dropdownlist` wont be bound at all